# What is the purpose of decodeTopLevelObjectOfClass for unarchieving

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why we should use decodeTopLevelObjectOfClass instead decodeObjectOfClass ? In my case decodeObjectOfClass is not working in case of nested custom object archieving.

Comment: "Those of you who have used NSCoders like NSKeyedArchiver or so on, you know there is no error arguments to those things. We have added explicit error handling. Methods such as these, Decode Object for Key and Decode Object of Classes for Key, now have versions that actually return errors, throw errors in Swift. They're named Decode Top Level Object for Key and Decode Top Level Object of Classes for Key. Note that they have throws declaration, which means that they return an error." From http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/202 Maybe worth a shot to watch that session.

Comment: @Larme Yes I see decodeTopLevelObjectOfClass added new error argument, Is there any other edge of it? In my case, I want to archive nested custom object, It is not working with decodeObjectOfClass. But it works well with decodeTopLevelObjectOfClass.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with `-[NSCoder error]`.

From the header comments in `NSCoder.h` for `-failWithError:`:

```
Sets an error on this NSCoder once per TopLevel decode; calling it
repeatedly will have no effect until the call stack unwinds to one
of the TopLevel decode entry-points.

This method is only meaningful to call for decodes.

Typically, you would want to call this method in your -initWithCoder:
implementation when you detect situations like:
 - lack of secure coding
 - corruption of your data
 - domain validation failures

After calling -failWithError: within your -initWithCoder:
implementation, you should clean up and return nil as early as possible.

Once an error has been signaled to a decoder, it remains set until
it has handed off to the first TopLevel decode invocation above it.
For example, consider the following call graph:
 A    -decodeTopLevelObjectForKey:error:
 B        -initWithCoder:
 C            -decodeObjectForKey:
 D                -initWithCoder:
 E                    -decodeObjectForKey:
 F                        -failWithError:

In this case the error provided in stack-frame F will be returned
via the outError in stack-frame A. Furthermore the result object
from decodeTopLevelObjectForKey:error: will be nil, regardless of
the result of stack-frame B.

NSCoder implementations support two mechanisms for the stack-unwinding from F to A:
 - forced (NSException based)
 - particpatory (error based)

The kind of unwinding you get is determined by the decodingFailurePolicy
property of this NSCoder (which defaults to NSDecodingFailurePolicyRaiseException
to match historical behavior).
```

---

And for `-error`:

```
While .error is non-nil, all attempts to decode data from this
coder will return a nil/zero-equivalent value.

This error is consumed by a TopLevel decode API (which resets
this coder back to a being able to potentially decode data).
```